# Is it possible to run all the tests using mocha even if there are some failures?

Tags: npm, nestjs

I am working on a node.js application and would like to know if there is a way I can run all the unit tests from all the sub modules even if there are some test failures to know how many tests are failing in total to start putting the fixes for them. We use mocha for our tests on the back-end and jest for the ui.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that how the test runner works to begin with? It runs all the tests and reports all the failures?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I see `npm test` exit at the first failure. In our package.json, we have "test: mocha --exit 'src/**/*.spec.ts'". Are we missing some configuration to make all the tests run? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior for `mocha` is to run all the tests. If it is exiting after the first test failure, that would suggest that you are using the "bail" option typically enabled on the command line with either `--bail` or `-b`.

Relevant docs: https://mochajs.org/#-bail-b

It can also be caused by passing the option `{ bail: true }` to `mocha.setup()`. Look in your test runner and in your `package.json`.

Lastly, the least likely of these possibilities is that it could also be caused by using `this.bail()` somewhere in the Mocha test runner.